# Component does not load on the intended router outlet

Tags: angular

This is a duplicate of my question but I have made the question a little clearer. I have 2 routing admin-layout.routing.ts and parameter.routing.ts
in the admin-layout.routing.ts I have a path for property.component.ts and it has a child called parameter.component.ts. In this parameter.component.ts I have a router outlet where I want the soa-date.component.ts to come out. I can get to the soa-date.component.ts but it's not showing in the intended second router-outlet. It just comes out on the first router-outlet. I don't have any errors either.

**admin-layout.routing.ts**

```
{ path: 'property',       component: PropertyComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
        { path: '', component: ParametersComponent,
            loadChildren: '../../property/parameters/parameters.module#ParmetersModule'
        }
    ]
},
{ path: 'person',         component: PersonComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
```

**parameters.routing.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SoaDateComponent } from './soa-date/soa-date.component';

export const ParametersRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'soadate', component: SoaDateComponent }
];
```

**parameters.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(ParametersRoutes),
    ],
    declarations: [
        SoaDateComponent
    ]
})

export class ParmetersModule { }
```

**parameters.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/soadate']" routerLinkActive="active" >SOA DATE</a>
<router-outlet name="paramOutlet"></router-outlet>
```

I need your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's not enough code to dubug this issue, I have created a stackblitz from what I understood the problem is.
I think you need to create a `parent-children` structure here to achieve what you are looking for.

And one more thing are you including `ParametersComponent` in `declarations` of any component?

Anyways here's the stackblitz,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yashpatelyk-routing-inap6y

If I am not wrong here's what you are trying to achieve,

`App` > `PropertyComponent` > `ParametersComponent` > `SoaDateComponent`

In my example click on the links that show up and you will see above stucture i.e `SoaDateComponent` is getting loaded in `ParametersComponent` correctly.
The code that might help you is in `parameters.module.ts`

Comment: I have included the parameters.component in the admin-layout component since I am using the <app-parameters> in the property,component.ts. I can get to the soadate.component but it is not rendering on the <router-outlet> in the parameters.component rather, it is rendering on the <router-outlet> of the property in the admin-layout component.

Comment: If I don't put the paramers.component in the admin-layout.module, I cannot use the <app-parameters> in the property.component.

Comment: Also, would it make a difference since I am using .forChild instead of .forRoot()?

Comment: See I updated the stackbitz, and made different module for property and parameter, property does use <parameter></parameter> as I have imported it's module in property module. tell me if you have any question.